# Who is the woman in the silver Mercedes?

Tags: character, ncis

Early on in the first season of NCIS, many episodes end with Agent Gibbs being picked up by a red haired woman in a silver Mercedes;

[image]

[image]

It is mentioned frequently that Gibbs is into red haired women, but during this period of time it's also established that he's just broken up with his latest wife and I don't remember there being any mention of who this woman is.

Who is the woman in the silver Mercedes? Is this ever explained?

Comment: I am thinking it could be Gibb's sister or an ex-wives.

Comment: Mark Harmons real life wife Pam Dauber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the [NCIS wiki](http://ncis.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Red-Head), she is known as the "Mysterious Red-Head".  She was never identified in the show.  The
role was played by Vivienne Bellisario, the fourth wife of NCIS producer Donald P. Bellisario and mother of Sean Murray, who played McGee.